# i3 or i5 Processor Good Enough for Adobe Design Suite?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, intel-core-i5, adobe-indesign, intel-core-i3

I am looking at investing in a new laptop. I am stuck between an i5 and an i3 processor. The prices differ quite a bit.

I will be running programs like illustrator, photshop and indesign but all for very basic design work (think wedding stationery and some basic graphic design).

Can I get away with an i3?

Thank you!

Comment: Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic

Comment: I posted a little while back that the biggest bottle neck I found for Photoshop was disk speed. http://superuser.com/questions/677722/faster-processor-or-more-ram/677728#677728
I would say for light work an i3 would be fine with an SSD...

Answer (score -1):

I can only speak for myself, but on my old AMD Duo Core PS CS 5 works OK. The bigger issue is the 4GB of RAM.
So I wouldn't worry too much. After all, if you are not satisfied with it, wipe it and send it back.